# Alternative way to manage / order content in Orchard

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

In most CMS products there is a way to order and manage the content in a folder structure. This same folder structure is also used for the site navigation and sitemap.

Is there also a way to do this in Orchard? Because I see that Orchard works in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: you can use the containable and container parts to organize your contents in a hierarchy, but the recommended (and much more flexible) approach is taxonomies.